# How can I create a Python class with a member named 'class'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a Python class that represents a  dictionary **my_dict** that I want to convert as follows

```
my_class = MyClass(**my_dict)
```

The issues is that one of the dicts keys is called 'class'

So when I do as follows Python complains:

```
class MyClass(BaseModel)
  name: str
  address: str
  id: int
  class: str                  <-- Python does not like me using the keyword class
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: A class is also an object and an attribute of an object can be set with `setattr`.

Comment: you can use `__annotations__['class'] = str` -- though every metaprogramming class I tried crashed in some other way later on with a `SyntaxError` building their `__init__` or `__new__` method

Comment: Usually you name it `klass` or `cls` or `class_` because of this restriction.

Comment: What is `BaseModel`? Is that from some framework, whose solution for this issue you should thus use?

Comment: @KellyBundy BaseModel is from pydantic

Comment: @anthonysottile your suggestion appeared to do the trick

Answer (score 1):

As deceze states in their comment, **the conventional way of resolving this issue is to suffix the name of the attribute with an underscore**. I'm sure there's probably *some* hacky way of getting an attribute named `class`, but it's probably not worth the pain of setting up and maintaining.

This is described in [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), which outlines style guidelines for Python code:

> `single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.
>
> ```py
> tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')
> ```